# SOAP-ERROR: Encoding: object hasn't 'first_name' property

Tags: php, .net, c#-4.0, soap, wsdl

I am getting the "SOAP-ERROR: Encoding: object hasn't 'first_name' property" error message in a .NET project when I am trying to call a web method that is written in PHP web service. The web method return a PHP array `$result_data`. I have added the elements in WSDL for the fields that the array is returning. As I am new to PHP, not able to get the structure of the returning array. The array seems to be of two level like.

```
$result_data => array(array( "first_name"
"last_name")

array( "first_name"
"last_name")

array( "first_name"
"last_name")
)
```

Here is my WSDL:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<wsdl:definitions
    xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"
    xmlns:tm="http://microsoft.com/wsdl/mime/textMatching/"
    xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"
    xmlns:mime="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/mime/"
    xmlns:tns="http://10.20.1.161/api/soap/"
    xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:soap12="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap12/"
    xmlns:http="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/http/"
    targetNamespace="http://10.20.1.161/api/soap/"
    xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/">

<wsdl:types>
<s:schema targetNamespace="http://10.20.1.161/api/soap/" elementFormDefault="qualified">
    <s:import namespace="http://microsoft.com/wsdl/types/"/>

    <s:element name="getUsers">
        <s:complexType>
            <s:sequence>
                <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="message" type="s:string"/>
            </s:sequence>
        </s:complexType>
    </s:element>

    <s:element name="getUsersResponse">
        <s:complexType>
            <s:sequence>
                <s:element name="getUsersArray" type="tns:getUsersArray"/>
            </s:sequence>
        </s:complexType>
    </s:element>

    <s:complexType name="getUsersArray">
        <s:sequence>
            <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" name="User" nillable="true" type="tns:User" />
        </s:sequence>
    </s:complexType>


    <s:complexType name="User">
        <s:sequence>
            <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="first_name" type="s:string"/>
            <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="last_name" type="s:string"/>
            <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="regular_time" type="s:string"/>
            <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="regular_time_wage" type="s:string"/>
            <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="regular_time_wage_with_burden" type="s:string"/>
            <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="regular_time_hourly_rate" type="s:string"/>
            <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="regular_time_hourly_rate_with_burden" type="s:string"/>
            <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="gross_wage" type="s:string"/>
            <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="gross_wage_with_burden" type="s:string"/>
            <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="worked_time" type="s:string"/>
            <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="worked_days" type="s:string"/>
            <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="verified_time_sheet" type="s:string"/>
            <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="verified_time_sheet_date" type="s:string"/>
       <!--     <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="absence_policy-3" type="s:string"/>
            <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="absence_policy-3_wage" type="s:string"/>
            <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="absence_policy-3_wage_with_burden" type="s:string"/>
            <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="absence_policy-3_hourly_rate" type="s:string"/>
            <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="absence_policy-3_hourly_rate_with_burden" type="s:string"/>-->
        </s:sequence>
    </s:complexType>
</s:schema>
</wsdl:types>

<wsdl:message name="getUsersSoapIn">
<wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:getUsers"/>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="getUsersSoapOut">
<wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:getUsersResponse"/>
</wsdl:message>

<wsdl:portType name="TestSoap">
<wsdl:operation name="getUsers">
    <wsdl:documentation xmlns:wsdl='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/'>
        Function ("getUsers")
    </wsdl:documentation>
    <wsdl:input message="tns:getUsersSoapIn"/>
    <wsdl:output message="tns:getUsersSoapOut"/>
</wsdl:operation>
</wsdl:portType>

<wsdl:portType name="TestSoap12">
<wsdl:operation name="getUsers">
    <wsdl:documentation xmlns:wsdl='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/'>
        Function ("getUsers")
    </wsdl:documentation>
    <wsdl:input message="tns:getUsersSoapIn"/>
    <wsdl:output message="tns:getUsersSoapOut"/>
</wsdl:operation>
</wsdl:portType>

<wsdl:binding name="TestSoap" type="tns:TestSoap">
<soap:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
<wsdl:operation name="getUsers">
    <soap:operation soapAction="http://10.20.1.161/api/soap/getUsers" style="document"/>
    <wsdl:input>
        <soap:body use="literal"/>
    </wsdl:input>
    <wsdl:output>
        <soap:body use="literal"/>
    </wsdl:output>
</wsdl:operation>
</wsdl:binding>

<wsdl:binding name="TestSoap12" type="tns:TestSoap12">
<soap12:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
<wsdl:operation name="getUsers">
    <soap12:operation soapAction="http://test-uri/soap/export/getUsers" style="document"/>
    <wsdl:input>
        <soap12:body use="literal"/>
    </wsdl:input>
    <wsdl:output>
        <soap12:body use="literal"/>
    </wsdl:output>
</wsdl:operation>
</wsdl:binding>

<wsdl:service name="TestService">
<wsdl:port name="TestPort" binding="tns:TestSoap">
    <soap:address location="http://10.20.1.161/api/soap/server.php"/>
</wsdl:port>
<wsdl:port name="TestSoap12" binding="tns:TestSoap12">
    <soap12:address location="http://10.20.1.161/api/soap/server.php"/>
</wsdl:port>
</wsdl:service>

</wsdl:definitions>
```

My portion of returning code.

```
$getUsersArray = $result->getResultData();
return array("getUsersArray" => $getUsersArray);
```

Please help.

Comment: You got any solution for that... !!

Answer (score 5):

The `first_name` property is marked as mandatory in your WSDL by `minOccurs="1"`. This error occurs when you are not setting `first_name` in your SOAP call. Add that parameter to your call and you should stop getting this error.